# How can we collect performance metrics from CAdvisor docker container?

Tags: docker, cadvisor

Sorry I just started to learn docker. My question may seem stupid for some of you.
In fact, I would like to know if there is a way to collect performance metrics from "CAdvisor" container (**not from cgroup**) **at runtime** ? I mean, extract performance values from the curves designed by cadvisor like memory usage or network traffic.
I need to record this values and save them in a database so that, I can perform a statistic analyzes upon these generated values (like comparing memory consumption for two docker containers at t=50s).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cAdvisor does provide a rest endpoint to get any stats in real time. By default, it keeps latest two minute of data. You can configure it to keep more or less. It also supports a storage backend to keep dumping stats to an influxdb database.

REST Api:

eg. /api/v1.3/containers
doc: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/api.md

Doc on setting up InfluxDB:
https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/influxdb.md

Answer (score 4):

As other answers mention, cAdvisor doesn't provide its own performance data API, instead it exposes metrics which are typically handled in a separate database if one wants to derive performance data beyond "real time". For example, cAdvisor exports Prometheus metrics natively:

http://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/

The Prometheus metric types:

http://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/

Prometheus supports a fairly rich functional expression language that can be used for querying and visualization:

http://prometheus.io/docs/querying/basics/

Comment: I would like to get the memory usage per container. Is it possible with cadvisor? (one single value/container)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use https://github.com/tutumcloud/container-metrics for this. Basically what that would be doing is using influxdb http://influxdb.com/ as a time series data store.

There is some more information available here: http://blog.tutum.co/2014/08/25/panamax-docker-application-template-with-cadvisor-elasticsearch-grafana-and-influxdb/

A couple of people seemed to be looking into the ELK stack (Elastic Search, Logstash, Kibana) for visualising some of this data here: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/634

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. So definitely, CAdvisor does not provide an API to get performance data right ? It must be integrated with either influxdb or ELK I think to access this data.

Comment: That's my understanding of it but I could be wrong.